# Mailchimp authentication showing Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, curl, oauth-2.0, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When integrating with mailchimp, I do authentication after I get access_token then I also send a get request to get metadata and faces a problem.

After synching user name and password I get access_token and I got error on this code:

```
var AccessToken = '<?php //echo $_GET['access_token']; ?>'
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: "https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata",
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'OAuth ' +      
        AccessToken );
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
} );
```

I also tried from curl as:

```
public function list()
{
  $url = 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token';
  $data = [
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => 345555555555555555555555,
    'client_secret' => '4b0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5406a7d',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/success',
    'code' => $_GET['code']
    ];
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec ($ch);
 $err = curl_error($ch);  //if you need
 curl_close ($ch);
 return $response;
     }
```

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ list:74
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your request states that **CORB**,

> Cross-origin read blocking, better known as CORB, is an algorithm by
>   which dubious cross-origin resource fetches are identified and blocked
>   before they reach a web page. CORB reduces the risk of leaking
>   sensitive data by keeping it further from cross-origin web pages. In
>   most browsers, it keeps such data out of untrusted script execution
>   contexts. In browsers with Site Isolation, it can keep such data out
>   of untrusted renderer processes entirely, helping even against side
>   channel attacks.

Since, you're making request from a localhost, it is being considered as dubious origin, as a result its being blocked.

Comment: can u suggest me how to get metedata from access_token in Oauth2